regex to match from space to space or question mark?
I'm trying to pull the url, without the query string from a field populated as shown below.  The pattern will always start with a space, but can end with a space or question mark.
\s(?P<test>.*)[\s] - this works for fields ending with a space

\s(?P<test>.*)[\?]- this works for fields ending with a ?

I'm not sure how to combine these two .  this \s(?P<test>.*)[\?|\s], does not seem to work per https://regex101.com/
Data Sample
"GET /test/pageone.do HTTP/1.1"
"GET /test/pagetwo.do?test1234 HTTP/1.1"

What language are you using?  Most languages today have URL parsing modules that understand all of the variations and escape codes that are encountered in URLs.

im trying to use the rex command in splunk to extract the page from our logs without the query string values.  Splunk appears to use the PCRE2 syntax

In character classes (within square brackets) you do not need the OR character (|). Your class should be [\?\s]-

You need a lazy quantifier, \s(?P<test>.*?)[?\s]

Match anything not a space or ?:
\s(?P<test>[^ ?]+)

But this will also match trailing input. To only capture the path, try this:
^[A-Z]+ (?P<test>[^ ?]+)

Which anchors the match to the start and consumes the web method.
